# Given Hermitian matrix A and x in $C^{n}$, show that if $c = xAx^{*}$, then c is real.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've basically set up the equation and inserted $AA^{*}$ so that I get the following:

$c = xAx^{*} = xAAA^{*}x^{*}$
$ c = (xA)A(xA)^{*}$

However, I'm a bit lost from here.  Thanks.

Comment: It is not true (in general) that $xAx^{*} = xAAA^{*}x^{*}$.

Comment: Should probably be $c=x^*Ax$, since if $x$ is $n\times 1$ and $A$ is $n\times n$ then $xA$ is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Take conjugate transpose on both sides of the equation $c=xAx^*$.

By the way, Hermitian means that $A=A^*$.